# Middleware for child route laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I'm looking to filter child routes for `admins` route, for example:

```php
get('admins/*', ['middleware' => 'auth', function() {}]);
```

I think in Laravel 4 was `Route::when('admins/*', '/');` to redirect user for `/` if not has auth by Call Pattern Filter from `filter.php`.

Is there someway to achieve that in Laravel 5.1?

Answer (score 2):

You could set the `admins` path as a group and set the middleware on the whole group:

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admins', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('some_admin_page', function () {
        # code...
    });
});
```

Another way to achieve it in case all 'admins' routes are under the same controller you can set in the constructor to call the middleware

```php
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```